# How can i import images in python turtle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I've made a python program and i don't know why it doesn't work.

i tried this code:

```
import turtle
screen=turtle.Screen()
opened_door="C:\Users\Roby&Gabry\Desktop\Monty Hall Paradox\opened_door.gif"
closed_door="C:\Users\Roby&Gabry\Desktop\Monty Hall Paradox\closed_door.gif"
screen.addshape(opened_door)
screen.addshape(closed_door)
t=turtle.Turtle()
t.shape(closed_door)
```

but every time i ran the program it gave me errors like this:

```
  File "c:\Users\Roby&Gabry\Desktop\Monty Hall Paradox\Monty Hall.py", line 3
    opened_door="C:\Users\Roby&Gabry\Desktop\Monty Hall Paradox\opened_door.gif"
                                                                                ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

where is the mistake??

Comment: The existing response is correct, however for more information read this answer :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2953843/792015

Answer (score 1):

The file paths contain backslashes, which is an escape character in Python. To get around this, you can prefix the strings with `r`:

```
opened_door=r"C:\Users\Roby&Gabry\Desktop\Monty Hall Paradox\opened_door.gif"
closed_door=r"C:\Users\Roby&Gabry\Desktop\Monty Hall Paradox\closed_door.gif"
```

Comment: Better yet, use pathlib or os.path to join the paths in an OS-agnostic way, and prefer relative rather than absolute paths, which fail if the project is moved.